# Codeigniter: Delete query with prepared statement

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

I'm not sure if this is a codeigniter thing or specifically a mysqli thing.

In my model class I'm trying to delete using 2 WHERE arguments:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id = ? AND company_id = ?";
$result = $this->db->query( $query, $user_id, '1' );
```

Error message:
    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? AND company_id = ?' at line 1

Any ideas?

Comment: put bind on array like : $result = $this->db->query( $query, array($user_id, '1') );

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use 'active record'

```
$this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
$this->db->where('company_id', 1);
$this->db->delete('users');
```

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: This did the trick. With a typical query you would have something like $result = //query and then $result is TRUE or FALSE, with active record and query builder is this possible or not even necessary?

Comment: Basically in codeigniter `$this->db->delete()` is return void type. But you can get affected rows `$this->db->affected_rows()` or `$this->db->_error_message()`. It helps you determine TRUE or FALSE to return.

Answer (score 0):

using active record is ok but using native SQL takes less resources , I quote:

> Note: If you intend to write your own queries you can disable active record 
>   in your database config file, allowing the core database library
>   and adapter to utilize fewer resources.

source : https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

here is my two lines

```
$query_string = "DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id =".$user_id." AND company_id = 1";
$query= $this->db->query($query_string); // will return True if SUCCESS
```

Comment: Ah good call. That's why it was giving me the error. Well I'm creating an app from scratch to I'm not sure which way I'll go

Comment: I use native queries all the time and  no complain, they call me dinosaur at work so...dinosaur it is